# should i build an iphone or web app

Tags: iphone

is there are good material on determining if you should build an iphone app or simply a web app that can be used on an iphone, regular browser etc . .

is the app store visibility the main reason to build an actual app for the iphone as it obviously seems like the browser solution is more available.

Comment: I read somewhere that a lot of apps are just fancy RSS feed Readers anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have both, that way you can charge twice and reuse a lot of the serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

Appstore can make you money. Either appstore or web app still needs to attract users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn Objective-C go for it! [Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/products/iphone-view-controllers-part-i) has a great screencast to get you started with iPhone Development. If you don't want to learn anything then stick with web.